# Spring JPA Async Save

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, completable-future

I'm trying to save a large `List` (+100K items) created from an XLS file with the `CrudRepository.saveAll()` method. Because of data size, the `saveAll` method takes a long time to run, so I'm trying to partition the list using Apache Commons Collections `ListUtils.partition` and calling the `saveAll` method in a loop, to improve performance:

```java
public interface ClaimsSegmentRepository extends CrudRepository<ClaimsSegment, String> {}

public class FileLoaderService {
    @Async("asyncFileLoadExecutor")
    public CompletableFuture<List<String>> loadFile(String fileName) throws Exception {
        for(List<ClaimsSegment> claimsSegmentGrp : ListUtils.partition(claimsSegmentList, MAX_PARTITION_SIZE)) {
            CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> claimSegmentRepo.saveAll(claimsSegmentGrp))
                .thenAccept(claimSegmentList -> {
                   //Processing child objects for Claim Segment List
                });
    }
}
```

This is throwing the error `HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements`, so I read some more online and saw this recommendation for my repo class:

```java
public interface ClaimsSegmentRepository extends CrudRepository<ClaimsSegment, String> {
    @Async
    <S extends ClaimsSegment> CompletableFuture<S> saveAll()
}
```

However, that is resulting in a compilation error complaining about return type mismatch:

```java
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
    Error creating bean with name 'loadController':
        Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'loaderSvc'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
            Error creating bean with name 'fileLoaderService' defined in file [Path\to\file\FileLoaderService.class]:
                Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:
                    Failed to instantiate [nom.side.xls.service.FileLoaderService]:
                        Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method saveAll(Iterable<ClaimsSegment>) is ambiguous for the type ClaimsSegmentRepository

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at nom.side.xls.ExcelFileLoaderApplication.main(ExcelFileLoaderApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    ...
```

The `@Async` annotation works fine for the `find` methods, but not for `save` and `saveAll`. Could someone please point out what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a bulk insert with Spring Boot and Spring Data JPA you need only two things:

1. set the option spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size to appropriate value you need (for example: 20)
2. use saveAll() method of your repo with the list of entities prepared for inserting.

Working example is [here](https://github.com/Cepr0/sb-jpa-batch-insert-demo).